# Logger not printing with log4j.properties within Spring Boot 1.5.7

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j

I'm using slf4j-api for logging and log4j as a logger. But in my Spring Boot project it doesn't show proper logs with custom log4j settings in `log4j.properties`.

**POM**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

**log4j.properties**:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

It prints something like:

```
2018-10-29 13:47:40.601  INFO 7740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] k.a.o.controller.CustomController     : 2018-08-02 2018-08-04
```

so, it doesn't show the line where it has been logged.
Should I add anything else?

Comment: Do you have an logback.xml file in your project?

Comment: Can you try the following one? `log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%l - %m%n`

Comment: @juliocb92 no, I don't have. Is it necessary? I though that `log4j.properties` is enough

Comment: @Zico I've tried... No results =(

Comment: @catscoolzhyk no, it is not. That file is for configure the log in an external file. Maybe you can not see the terminal log beacuse of that.

Answer (score 1):

**slf4j-api** by itself doesn't provide any concrete implementation of logging system. It's a set of interfaces if you wish.

**So adding only slf4j-api is not enough.**

Logback as was suggested in comments, contains a real implementation of logging system.
This library can be imported explicitly of, if you prefer a zero logging configuration, make sure that spring-boot-starter-logging is imported.

So, logback should be used as an alternative to log4j which is also a real implementation of logging system (it also can be used, but frankly speaking logback is superior to log4j1 in terms of functionality, so I don't see any reason to do so).

Once you have logback, the way to set it is to provide a logback.xml file in resources that should contain any configuration you need there.

Comment: Thank you @MarkBramnik I will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *default* logger to print your desired pattern, you just need to add the following in your `application.properties`:

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Spring Boot provides `Logback` as its default logger. Also adding a `logback.xml` in your `CLASSPATH` will allow you to better configure everything else such as `Appenders`, `Patterns` etc (*You may do the same through `application.properties` also*).

As **@MarkBrammik** already mentions, `sl4j` is only an abstraction and is therefore not enough. We use `sl4j` as an interface to utilize other concrete logging APIs such as `Logback`, `log4j`, `JDK(java.util.logging)`, etc.

Additionally, if you want to use `log4j`, then you will have to add the following dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and then you may further configure it using a `log4j.properties` placed in your `CLASSPATH`. If you use `log4j` you will have to exclude `Logback` from your Spring dependencies, or else you may get the `Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings` error :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You may check out the link provided below for more info and I hope you will find it useful : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html